# How or where to store FCM Background notification data in Hive in Flutter iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, background, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-hive

1. Both ios and AOS receive background notification normally.
2. In AOS, received background notification data can be stored in Hive through backgroundHandler.
3. But in ios BackgroundHander doesn't work.
4. If BackgroundHandler is not supported on iOS, is there another way?
5. Is it not possible to save background notification data to Hive in iOS?

---

**BackgroundHandler**

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(1)) {
    Hive.registerAdapter<PushNotificationModel>(PushNotificationModelAdapter());
  }

  final documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(documentDirectory.path);
  if (Hive.isBoxOpen(HiveBoxConstant.BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_LIST)) {
    await Hive.box<PushNotificationModel>(HiveBoxConstant.BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_LIST).close();
  }
  if (Hive.isBoxOpen(HiveBoxConstant.NOTIFICATION_LIST)) {
    await Hive.box<PushNotificationModel>(HiveBoxConstant.NOTIFICATION_LIST).close();
  }
  await Hive.openBox<PushNotificationModel>(HiveBoxConstant.BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_LIST);
  await Hive.openBox<PushNotificationModel>(HiveBoxConstant.NOTIFICATION_LIST);

  await FCMManager.saveNotificationList(message, true);

  if (Hive.isBoxOpen(HiveBoxConstant.BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_LIST)) {
    await Hive.box<PushNotificationModel>(HiveBoxConstant.BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_LIST).close();
  }
  if (Hive.isBoxOpen(HiveBoxConstant.NOTIFICATION_LIST)) {
    await Hive.box<PushNotificationModel>(HiveBoxConstant.NOTIFICATION_LIST).close();
  }
}
```

---

**Main**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

...

  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);


  runApp(
  ...
  );
}

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorStateGlobalKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class AppMain extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const AppMain({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<AppMain> createState() => _AppMainState();
}

class _AppMainState extends ConsumerState<AppMain> with WidgetsBindingObserver {


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      ...
    );
  }

}
```

---

**iOS Payload**

```
payload: {
    'aps': {
        'badge': 1,
        'sound': 'default',
        'content_available':true,
        'mutable_content':true,
        }
    },
    headers: {
        "apns-priority": "10",
    },
```

---

**xcode**
[image]

```
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
      }

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
```

Comment: I received @Kasymbek R. Tashbaev's answer and added payload information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to save background notification data to Hive in iOS.

I used to experience issues with the Firebase background message handler not working on iOS. The solution was to adjust the payload configuration by setting specific values for the `mutable-content` and `content-available` properties.

```
apns: {
    payload: {
        aps: {
            'mutable-content': 1, 
            'content-available': 1
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that the `mutable-content` property may or may not need to be set to true for your specific use case. I recommend conducting your own testing to verify if the changes resolve the problem without setting `mutable-content` to true.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
but already sending it with the payload below.
Are there any additional expected causes of the error?

payload: {
            'aps': {
                'badge': 1,
                'sound': 'default',
                'content_available':true,
                'mutable_content':true,
            }
        },

Comment: What about settings in XCode, did you enable background processing and remote notifications?

Comment: yes. enabled all.